# How to fix Middle Man Injection while opening a file from a relative path?

Tags: java, file

Attackers are able to control the file system path argument to File() which allows them to access or modify otherwise protected files.

```
String strTempDwnldLoc = dms.DMSStartup.getProperty("WebTempDownloadDir") + "/";
File file2 = null;

    .....

try {
    file2 = new File(strTempDwnldLoc+dtoList.get(i)
                     .getDoc_relative_path().split("/")[1]);    
    if (file2.exists()){
      file2.delete();
    }
} catch(Exception e){    
    .....
}
```

I am Using Java 6, hence not able to use `java.nio` package. Otherwise I would have tried to validate the file path using `file.getCanonicalPath()` but unable to come up with a decent solution.

Comment: An application that provides access to files at remotely specified locations should probably also be sandboxed on the OS level (i.e. put in a container). That way, you can limit what files it can see (no matter how broken/insecure the application code is).

Comment: @Thilo The developer always assume that the program environment is secure but that is rarely the situation, we must validate every user input, File locations and parameters to SQL queary to ensure the security.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that we're trying to solve with this is when an attacker sends a
path like ../../../../../../../etc/passwd.  A Java web application might
happily serve up the passwd file to the attacker.  So we force the use of
canonical paths.  This may not be convenient in many applications, but it is
pretty important.
In this case, "../conf/" will be only one physical place on the file
system since the value is tacked onto the project's base directory path
(which i've defined as the "parent" argument), therefore it is a known.

the recent addition of the "parent" argument would suggest the input path
doesn't have to be a canonical path.  here is the method call:
getValidDirectoryPath("Context", "../conf/", ".", false);

```
  public void testGetValidDirectoryPath() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("getValidDirectoryPath");
    Validator instance = ESAPI.validator();
    ValidationErrorList errors = new ValidationErrorList();
    // find a directory that exists
    File parent = new File("/");
    String path = ESAPI.securityConfiguration().getResourceFile("ESAPI.properties").getParentFile().getCanonicalPath();
    instance.getValidDirectoryPath("dirtest1", path, parent, true, errors);
    assertEquals(0, errors.size());
    instance.getValidDirectoryPath("dirtest2", null, parent, false, errors);
    assertEquals(1, errors.size());
    instance.getValidDirectoryPath("dirtest3", "ridicul%00ous", parent, false, errors);
    assertEquals(2, errors.size());
}
```

Visit The following website for more information :
https://www.jtmelton.com/2010/05/02/the-owasp-top-ten-and-esapi-part-4-malicious-file-execution/